# Oracle Apex -> Add App Title substitution string in 2 lines

Tags: html, oracle-apex

I have to change the Application title coming on pages using Application Properties-> Substitution strng -> APP_TITLE property.

The title i want displayed is :

```
PROJECT MATRIX
         CARE
```

So the CARE in second line should be 1 font size smaller and aligned towards right.
As of now i tried : `PROJECT MATRIX <br> <font size = "2"> CARE </font size> </br>`
This is putting CARE below the first line and reducing size, but how do i right align that second line?

Oracle Apex : 20.2

Answer (score 0):

I've duplicated and modified the Standard Page template to make changes to the header in the past.

I am also on [oracle-apex] 20.2. Where can I find Application Properties-> Substitution strng -> APP_TITLE property?

Regards
David

PS: I found this online

```
<p style="text-align:left;">
    This text is left aligned
    <span style="float:right;">
        This text is right aligned
    </span>
</p>
```

Comment: Shared componenets-> Application definition attributes -> Substitutions-> APP_TITLE